# Failed to launch Appium Settings app: Condition unmet after 5071 ms. Timing out

Tags: android, mobile, appium

I'm trying to run my first mobile automation script and getting an error

> "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to launch Appium Settings app: Condition unmet after 5071 ms. Timing out".

My code is :

```
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
   from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
   from appium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

   desired_caps = {}
   desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
   desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '5.1.1'
   desired_caps['deviceId'] = '*.*.*.*:5555'
   desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'A0001'
   # subprocess.call('adb shell input keyevent 26 && adb shell input swipe 
   # 200 900 200 300',shell=True)
   desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'com.android.vending'
   desired_caps['appActivity'] = 
   'com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity'
   app_name = "Facebook"
   app_description = "Facebook for mobile"
   driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
   search_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 
   60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR,'new 
   UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.vending:id/search_bar_hint")')))
   search_element.click()
   text_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 
   60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 
   'new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText")')))
   text_element.send_keys(app_name + "\n")
   driver.press_keycode(66)
   app_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 
   60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR,'new 
   UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.vending:id/play_card")')))
   app_elements.click()
   install_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 
   60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((MobileBy.ANDROID_UIAUTOMATOR, 
   'new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.vending:id/right_button")')))
   install_button.click()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to launch Appium Settings app: Condition unmet after 5071 ms. Timing out.

Comment: Above is the error message I'm getting